# First reference review biblatex-sbl with exact page number

Tags: biblatex

I am using Biblatex-sbl and I am wondering that the page-numbering of the first quotation in some of the fields (such as @review) are permanently fully displayed - this is not the case in the next mentionings of the same literature. My problem: In some cases, these first mentionings are verbally quotations, so that an exact pagination is required (see the first note of the MWE). It is possible to have sth. like:

> Julius Wellhausen, Rezension von select, Paris/ Leipzig 1905,von Paul
>   Ban, LM 8,2(1906): 16–18 (here 17).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}

@book{Pritchard:1969,
  editor    = {Pritchard, James B.},
  title     = {Ancient Near Eastern Texts Relating to the Old Testament},
  edition   = {3},
  location  = {Princeton},
  publisher = {Princeton University Press},
  date      = {1969},
}
@article{Kriger.1907,
 author = {Kriger, John},
 date = {1907},
 title = {Forum Romanun},
shorttitle = {Forum},
 pages = {11--14},
 volume = {6},
journaltitle = {Le Muséon},
shortjournal = {LM},
}

@review{Wellhausen.1906,
author={Wellhausen, Julius},
revdauthor = {Ban, Paul},
revdtitle={select, Paris/ Leipzig 1905},
journaltitle = {Le Museon},
shortjournal = {LM},
volume={8,2},
date={1906},
pages={16--18},
}



\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\printbiblist{abbreviations}

Die Debatten sind nach Meinung von Wellhausen „ein AUsdruck zeitgenössischer Debatten“\footnote{\cite[164]{Wellhausen.1906}.}. An anderer Stelle wird er sogar noch deutlicher.\footnote{Siehe auch: \cite{Pritchard:1969}.}
Es geht.\footnote{\cite[164]{Kriger.1907}.} sdf\footnote{Vgl. \cite[{84 {[hebr.]}}; 99 {[dt.]}]{Kriger.1907}.}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: `citepages=separate`?

Comment: https://github.com/dcpurton/biblatex-sbl/issues/109

Comment: Please don't edit your question with a new question after it has been answered. Ask a *new* question  about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option `citepages=separate,` displays the contents of the `pages` field on a first citation and adds the `postnote` field with a special string (`thiscite` which is "hier" in German). There are more possible values for that option, the [`biblatex-sbl` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-sbl/biblatex-sbl.pdf) explains the options and illustrates them with useful examples on pp. 4-5.

There is a small typo in `biblatex-sbl` with that option (https://github.com/dcpurton/biblatex-sbl/issues/109), so we need a little more code than usual. When the issue is fixed, the `\renewbibmacro*{pages}` block can be deleted. The issue has already been resolved on GitHub.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl, citepages=separate]{biblatex}


\renewbibmacro*{pages}{%
  \iffieldundef{pages}
    {\ifbool{bbx@inset}
       {}
       {\printfield{postnote}%
        \global\booltrue{suppresspostnote}}}
    {\printfield{pages}%
     \ifboolexpr{
       test {\iffieldundef{postnote}}
       or
       bool {bbx@inset}
     }
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
         \printtext[parens]{%
          \iffieldpages{postnote}
            {\bibstring{thiscite}%
             \setunit{\addspace}}
            {}%
          \printfield{postnote}}}}}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Pritchard:1969,
  editor    = {Pritchard, James B.},
  title     = {Ancient Near Eastern Texts Relating to the Old Testament},
  edition   = {3},
  location  = {Princeton},
  publisher = {Princeton University Press},
  date      = {1969},
}
@review{Wellhausen.1906,
  author={Wellhausen, Julius},
  revdauthor   = {Ban, Paul},
  revdtitle    = {select, Paris/ Leipzig 1905},
  journaltitle = {Le Museon},
  shortjournal = {LM},
  volume       = {8,2},
  date         = {1906},
  pages        = {16--18},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\printbiblist{abbreviations}

Die Debatten sind nach Meinung von Wellhausen „ein AUsdruck zeitgenössischer Debatten“\autocite[164]{Wellhausen.1906}.
An anderer Stelle wird er sogar noch deutlicher.\autocite[Siehe auch][]{Pritchard:1969}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: Julius Wellhausen, Rezension von select, Paris/ Leipzig 1905, von Paul Ban, LM 8,2 (1906): 16–18 (hier 164).]