# 2 exact page numbers in footnotes biblatex-sbl

Tags: biblatex

I am using Biblatex-sbl and I had a little problem that came after this post here: [First reference review biblatex-sbl with exact page number](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/505821/first-reference-review-biblatex-sbl-with-exact-page-number) I have an article where a source has been published together with a translation. When I first quoted it, the "hier" will not be shown resp. the result is (see note 3):

> Vgl. John Kriger, „Forum Romanun“,LM6 (1907): 11–14 (11 [syr.], 12
>   [dt.]).

The correct result should be:

> Vgl. John Kriger, „Forum Romanun“,LM6 (1907): 11–14 (here 11 [syr.],
>   12 [dt.]).

Vgl. Kriger, „Forum“, 11–14 (11 [dt.], 14 [engl.]). The second problem is that the following notes display it with the complete page numbering, e.g. (see note 5):

> Vgl. Kriger, „Forum“, 11–14 (11 [syr.], 12 [dt.]).

It should be:

> Vgl. Kriger, „Forum“, 11 [syr.], 12 [dt.]

. What Iam doing wrong? Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl, citepages=separate]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{pages}{%
  \iffieldundef{pages}
    {\ifbool{bbx@inset}
       {}
       {\printfield{postnote}%
        \global\booltrue{suppresspostnote}}}
    {\printfield{pages}%
     \ifboolexpr{
       test {\iffieldundef{postnote}}
       or
       bool {bbx@inset}
     }
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
         \printtext[parens]{%
          \iffieldpages{postnote}
            {\bibstring{thiscite}%
             \setunit{\addspace}}
            {}%
          \printfield{postnote}}}}}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Pritchard:1969,
  editor    = {Pritchard, James B.},
  title     = {Ancient Near Eastern Texts Relating to the Old Testament},
  edition   = {3},
  location  = {Princeton},
  publisher = {Princeton University Press},
  date      = {1969},
}
@article{Kriger.1907,
 author = {Kriger, John},
 date = {1907},
 title = {Forum Romanun},
shorttitle = {Forum},
 pages = {11--14},
 volume = {6},
journaltitle = {Le Muséon},
shortjournal = {LM},
}

@review{Wellhausen.1906,
  author={Wellhausen, Julius},
  revdauthor   = {Ban, Paul},
  revdtitle    = {select, Paris/ Leipzig 1905},
  journaltitle = {Le Museon},
  shortjournal = {LM},
  volume       = {8,2},
  date         = {1906},
  pages        = {16--18},
}

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\printbiblist{abbreviations}

Die Debatten sind nach Meinung von Wellhausen „ein AUsdruck zeitgenössischer Debatten“\autocite[164]{Wellhausen.1906}.
An anderer Stelle wird er sogar noch deutlicher.\autocite[Siehe auch][]{Pritchard:1969}
Grer\footnote{Vgl. \cite[{11 {[dt.]}}; 12 {[engl.]}]{Kriger.1907}.}
Grer\footnote{\cite[11.12.13]{Kriger.1907}.}

sdf\footnote{Vgl. \cite[{11 {[dt.]}}; 12 {[eng.]}]{Kriger.1907}{.}}
adfist aufgelistet


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason "here" isn't printed for note 3 is because `biblatex` thinks your `postnote` is not a page number. It thinks this because of the "[dt.]" and "[engl.]". Notice the `\iffieldpages` test in the `pages` macro in your MWE.

I did things this way because if your `postnote` *really* isn't a page number, then you don't want "here" printed.

There are two options. You can either manually include the "here" in your `postnote` in such cases. Or you can remove the `\iffieldpages` test. I show how to do the latter below. To add it manually you could do something like this:

```
autocite[Vgl\adddot][\ifciteseen{}{\bibstring{thiscite}} {11 {[dt.]}}; 12 {[engl.]}]{Kriger.1907}
```

The problem with note 5 is slightly different. For whatever reason, when I first wrote `biblatex-sbl` I decided that `pages` should be printed in subsequent citations if either no `postnote` were given or if the `postnote` were not a page range.

I have since decided that this is a stupid idea. And it will not do this in the next version of `biblatex-sbl`. It's fixed in `github`. Unfortunately, the fixes needed for this require quite a lot of changes :(. See https://github.com/dcpurton/biblatex-sbl/issues/93. I wonder whether you might consider using the development version of `biblatex-sbl`?

Here's a temporary fix for both these issues, although the fix for note 5 is only very simplistic. For the next release, you should only have to worry about "here" not being printed when the `postnote` is not a page range, as I still think this is probably the most sensible option.

## MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}

\usepackage[german=quotes]{csquotes}
\usepackage[style=sbl,
citepages=separate
]{biblatex}

\renewbibmacro*{postnote}{%
  \iftoggle{blx@unit}
    {}
    {\newunit}%
  \printfield{postnote}}

\renewbibmacro*{pages}{%
  \iffieldundef{pages}
    {\ifbool{bbx@inset}
       {}
       {\printfield{postnote}%
        \global\booltrue{suppresspostnote}}}
    {\printfield{pages}%
     \ifboolexpr{
       test {\iffieldundef{postnote}}
       or
       bool {bbx@inset}
     }
       {}
       {\setunit{\addspace}%
         \printtext[parens]{%
           \bibstring{thiscite}%
           \setunit{\addspace}%
           \printfield{postnote}}}}}


\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@book{Pritchard:1969,
  editor    = {Pritchard, James B.},
  title     = {Ancient Near Eastern Texts Relating to the Old Testament},
  edition   = {3},
  location  = {Princeton},
  publisher = {Princeton University Press},
  date      = {1969},
}
@article{Kriger.1907,
 author = {Kriger, John},
 date = {1907},
 title = {Forum Romanun},
shorttitle = {Forum},
 pages = {11--14},
 volume = {6},
journaltitle = {Le Muséon},
shortjournal = {LM},
}

@review{Wellhausen.1906,
  author={Wellhausen, Julius},
  revdauthor   = {Ban, Paul},
  revdtitle    = {select, Paris/ Leipzig 1905},
  journaltitle = {Le Museon},
  shortjournal = {LM},
  volume       = {8,2},
  date         = {1906},
  pages        = {16--18},
}

\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
\null\vfill
\printbiblist{abbreviations}

Die Debatten sind nach Meinung von Wellhausen „ein AUsdruck zeitgenössischer Debatten“\autocite[164]{Wellhausen.1906}.
An anderer Stelle wird er sogar noch deutlicher.\autocite[Siehe auch][]{Pritchard:1969}
Grer\footnote{Vgl. \cite[{11 {[dt.]}}; 12 {[engl.]}]{Kriger.1907}.}
Grer\footnote{\cite[11.12.13]{Kriger.1907}.}

sdf\footnote{Vgl. \cite[{11 {[dt.]}}; 12 {[eng.]}]{Kriger.1907}{.}}
adfist aufgelistet


\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: MWE output]

Comment: Maybe it would be good to have a command to locally tell `biblatex` to treat text that is not a page range as if it were for the purposes of `\iffieldpages`/`\ifpages`. I'm just not sure how one would do this. Do you think this would be useful?

Comment: @moewe, this might be useful. I have no idea how these tests work now though, so I don't know how hard it would be to implement. Some way to temporarily set `\DeclarePageCommands` to a wildcard matching everything?

Comment: Logged at https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/918.